# yahoo finance options data using python requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the following url as it appears to me in chrome:
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=MSFT&date=1414713600

For chrome 37 and linux, it appears with the table headers:
Strike, Contract Name, Last, Bid, Ask, Change, %Change, Volume, Open Interest, Implied Volatility

When I grab it with python requests library, it returns a table with the headers.
"Strike Symbol  Last    Chg Bid Ask Vol Open Interest"

```
url =  "http://finance.yahoo.com/q/op?s=MSFT&date=1414713600"
text = requests.get(url)
```

Is there any way to use requests to get the data in the same manner as it appears in chrome?  I assume I have to send a change in headers, but I have tried a number of different things that have not worked.
my last try was the following:

```
 headers = {
   'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
   'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36',
   'content-type': 'application/json'
 }
```

here are the headers chrome sends for me to get the website I want:

```
GET /q/op?s=MSFT&date=1413590400 HTTP/1.1
Host: finance.yahoo.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Cookie: PREF=ID=a6c1e76064f94d39:U=827f4a5f7ace80ef:FF=0:LD=en:TM=1405040931:LM=1410201670:GM=1:S=btbAGy8zLyRsY3Qr; SID=DQAAACwCAADXppdnRkNOk3FSR5EzCt5fvxdXMAH87uz4j_4Xm2aM-zbhU5JEXVw93LhmIjRCf2B-nonvZv4hXuO_V2FYXsdOYCxigM7jpBxhd1RcK-zfzM1w5SrEa6Q5aFfBHvU6p5KkPQ8v4m8srb_k0cxAzf7x5KRlkZ5llB5oDLpiPPUhFORd7y2xobzHvIo9YJ92pv8kmCnPWnNfMUUMK6XEoov56B1SmfJ8XUTyRN3oBIe0MKAPodTznhLlB0_qzqG1ohjEIv_WoiauvWNzmLGuzmQqAuHlMswIBnF5S0ECJ7sb-6Nap9FITjCnJfrelTqTH782wJL9pC7SGlU0L1LTkBb_j1Zmy4HI2eItaNhFXy-LIWF2hX88ijAQkYas0SrBvLC7d-SC58mLuvqwW4ZHntTCkIvRv1ZUs8fQPFCLl-WbmHcHhgavmVeEGXuCNAmzcAkslJ_eBghQUlbPPOqEAzNMgWrJkAzVcQBTxhYi2P8mQ4_c91L7mFeLe_NspFLCoWLnlIyfxwfVma6fpOGpGgg3eWydiOWT-WcNzNnY6P1TrN0gIL4QZvaD7VdBkvMJVtUeFHhxjZE5535Gddg1g1N469MesuGcIEISjOtjoBMpYMjmbRvIV4UyKSTFzSiqxZxOI0uSn1w-acf5g6G4tBmbfU_kSz1ass8ZV0rmiSrnTniNGWEg635jKCcTFND4KYuUJ1T21RlRP3q3btvejbzx29uuJxwWkR5KX0QR7CvVNQ; HSID=A2inQ1hxY_Akxsjaz; SSID=A9udoa1_RoYRXqu3b; APISID=LiX-ftG4pPZq-K4a/ALRoyKU_0PfrlgD5X; SAPISID=iVLeNwxPVKei4Q0q/Ayrp0XHMIQ5iq33wu; S=quotestreamer=6kIdj_SK-1Tobo0ctY2M3Q; NID=67=uQYk0bBnV8JbGB3UkfzG7f_1_vzYbCxH5BYU7_LjzwvN7WwEqe38sg93Um1eUxMlKDfgvuG2jpjL9UyjBI4gdGZDnMTDD21th6S0ptMJRh7HVCqxqzVMZMWtzQqaFOcCmHfNMp3wJBNwoynu2bsrJtNy5Kfz0TvaMkm-T6-_7h9PCTds7yzia46XVioSQl-8JYBbePrm9iaYYArRxMPl9mYs_5sEv5Noo4KRtKxUM4VpMGRx3Fykp1PMvMIU2T9cl2w9JiOGgryDuK-3b41Ihx326qpAdlAkB897bCf2TPl1AezTWf1UQOzTzv8XdPsvzd2sa4Sx0hND_Pi7rwPLHgzVOg9Sh3cqtUkjXycsKYWrVFIKfQCyy4g8sjKqwgvPQA; S=quotestreamer=6kIdj_SK-1Tobo0ctY2M3Q:talkgadget=aHfB4TSaCOCYGPzGrmtTLA
DNT: 1
Referer: https://579.talkgadget.google.com/talkgadget/d?token=AHRlWrqRUYIuQjAi1pH4ZFQhJWe92QrASI-PuFy3th_zCVENP71Zh90Pzs9Ch2JvJAf2qFw21V5oopm3dZRnzTTLl8UBAJ4co-b4WztC8owNbJhlYoVy-dS2lnsdBlXzcVph10ii8uFf&xpc=%7B%22cn%22%3A%22dV1z5gMTwj%22%2C%22tp%22%3Anull%2C%22osh%22%3Anull%2C%22ppu%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fmightytext.net%2F_ah%2Fchannel%2Fxpc_blank%22%2C%22lpu%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2F579.talkgadget.google.com%2Ftalkgadget%2Fxpc_blank%22%7D
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
X-Client-Data: CJa2yQEIprbJAQiptskBCN6WygE=

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Age: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Wed, 15 Oct 2014 12:08:23 GMT
Server: ATS
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: X-Ssl
Via: http/1.1 media-border67.global.media.bf1.yahoo.com (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ]), http/1.1 r18.ycpi.dcb.yahoo.net (ApacheTrafficServer [cMsSf ])
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: Your link gives me Strike,Symbol,... in Chrome on Windows.  Maybe you should just use that.

Comment: thanks John.   I am lost as why it appears different in my chrome browser in incognito mode then when I do requests.get

Comment: I wonder what parameter is making the change

Comment: Try using tcpdump or equivalent on your system to inspect the outgoing request in its entirety.  Or maybe Chrome Developer Tools will give you enough of a hint.  I can't help because my Chrome doesn't do what yours does.

Comment: Chrome and Safari on Mac OS gave me the same "bad" result.  I think you should just use the "bad" version because that's what most things actually receive anyway--including your script.  I even tried adding some of your headers with `curl` and got the same thing: Strike then Symbol.  Maybe you're logged in to Yahoo and have different settings?

Comment: I am not logged in. I usually use sites in a incognito window so it will be representative of what I will see when I scrape it

Comment: Yahoo seems to have updated the site to this way for everyone.